# Logical operation using length of text column in SQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column "names", which is defined as a text column. I want to select names which contain more than 10 characters. First thought was

```
WHERE len(names) > 10
```

"Len" doesn't work with text, though. I found out about DATALENGTH, but it doesnt't work either and I get a message that I should change column types.

Isn't there any way to do this while keeping this column as text?

Comment: Hint:  `length()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should try using `WHERE length(name) > 10`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the built-in [LENGTH](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-length-function/) function is all you need.  It works for char, varchar, text, etc.

```
select names, length(names) from myTable

select names from myTable where length(names) > 10
```